# Pixel manipulation using sdl

Tags: c, image, sdl

I am trying to manipulate pixel using sdl and manage to read them up now. Below is my sample code. When I print I this `printf("\npixelvalue is  is : %d",MyPixel);` I get values like this

```
11275780
11275776 
etc
```

I know these are not in hex form but how to manipulate say I want to filter just the blue colors out? Secondly after manipulation how to generate the new image?

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  SDL_Surface *screen, *image;
  SDL_Event event;
  Uint8 *keys;
  int done = 0;

  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
  {
    printf("Can't init SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
  }
  atexit(SDL_Quit);
  SDL_WM_SetCaption("sample1", "app.ico");

  /* obtain the SDL surfance of the video card */
  screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 24, SDL_HWSURFACE);
  if (screen == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't set video mode: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("Loading here");

  /* load BMP file */
  image = SDL_LoadBMP("testa.bmp");
  Uint32* pixels = (Uint32*)image->pixels;
  int width = image->w;
  int height = image->h;
  printf("Widts is : %d",image->w);

  for(int iH = 1; iH<=height; iH++)
    for(int iW = 1; iW<=width; iW++)
    {
      printf("\nIh is : %d",iH);
      printf("\nIw is : %d",iW);
      Uint32* MyPixel = pixels + ( (iH-1) + image->w ) + iW;
      printf("\npixelvalue is  is : %d",MyPixel);
    }

  if (image == NULL) {
    printf("Can't load image of tux: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Blit image to the video surface */
  SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screen, NULL);   
  SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, screen->w, screen->h);

  /* free the image if it is no longer needed */
  SDL_FreeSurface(image);

  /* process the keyboard event */
  while (!done)
  {
    // Poll input queue, run keyboard loop
    while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
    {
      if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) 
      {
        done = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    keys = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
    if (keys[SDLK_q])
    {
      done = 1;
    }
    // Release CPU for others
    SDL_Delay(100);
  }
  // Release memeory and Quit SDL
  SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Without indentation, it's pretty hard to read the code...

Comment: @AdamS is it better now.

Comment: %x instead of %d will give you the hex value. Usually colors are made up of red, green, blue. values. Maybe one byte in your Int32 for each. Maybe an additional alpha component.

Comment: Yes I know the first should be A the RGB right ? So how to manipulate any idea and how to save the manipulated image ?

Comment: Ok I changed to %x ready but I just see this now abOe04,abOe00 etc. So which one will be the alpha value then ?

Comment: I don't know SDL perhaps someone else does. You could look in the documentation for how the colors are defined in the word.

Comment: Ok thx charlie hopefully some one can help on this?

Comment: Surprisingly I change to full red image but its giving me 3662b0,3662ac etc should it be starting with FF000 ?

Comment: I don't really understand the question...? Maybe you are searching for a function called `SDL_GetRGB`?

Comment: @Yes I found at last in google it says user GETRGB.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SDL_MapRGB` and `SDL_MapRGBA` to sort colors out. SDL will filter it out for you, based on surface format.

Just like this:

```
Uint32 rawpixel = getpixel(surface, x, y);
Uint8 red, green, blue;

SDL_GetRGB(rawpixel, surface->format, &red, &green, &blue);
```

Comment: in my case how to call this in this correct Uint32* MyPixel = pixels + ( (iH-1) + image->w ) + iW; after this getpixel(image, x, y);. So what are these values that are being printed 3662b0,3662ac? arent they the hex values of rgb ?

Comment: @user2711681 You shouldn't use that kind of sentence in your code, because it makes it a horrible mess already. Create your own function that will get pixel value, don't use that crap.

Comment: I dont get about which codes you are speaking about? Can you point me which codes are they ?

Comment: @user2711681 I am talking about `Uint32* MyPixel = pixels + ( (iH-1) + image->w )`. Make a function `getpixel` or something like that, instead of using it. Also actually, SDL documentation has got valid `getpixel` function in it.

Comment: Ok I will look into it how to say I want to change the from a color pixel into 8 bit grey scale how to go about it ?

Comment: Are you referring to this for the getpixel http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Pixel_Access? How is the bpp value is decided?

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the value of the pointer `MyPixel`. To get the value you have to dereference the pointer to the pixel value like this: `*MyPixel`

Then the printf would look like this:

```
printf("\npixelvalue is : %d and the address of that pixel is: %p\n",*MyPixel , MyPixel);
```

Other errors:

1. Your for loops are incorrect. You should loop from 0 to less than width or height, or else you will read uninitialized memory.
2. You didn't lock the surface. Although you are only reading the pixels and nothing should go wrong it is still not correct.
3. Test for correctness if the `image` pointer comes after you are already using the pointer. Put the test right after the initialization.

Comment: ok I will update the printf as your suggestion. I will start the loop from 0. When to lock the surface before I do any process is it why is this needed?  How to test the correctness? So I want to change some pixel values how to go about it ?

Comment: you are right but I notice some are showing as showing as ff0000 some as ff00 only some as ff0000ff why is this all havign different format ?

Comment: @user2711681 Leading zeroes aren't printed.

Comment: @but why some are in this format ff00 so I guess the back is 00 right. How about this ff0000ff then why there is ff at the back is that the alpha value ?

Comment: I tried this code Uint32* MyPixel = pixels + ( (iH-1) + image->w ) + iW;
    printf("\npixelvalue is  is : %x\n",*MyPixel);
    *MyPixel = 0x00FFFF; why isnt my pixel value changed ?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly I used [sdl_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/) for pixel manipulation.

It also contains function like drawing a circle, oval etc.